# How to open Drawer When use a custom icon in Scene

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux, react-native-router-flux

I using Drawer my app, my problem is i want use a custom icon in Drawer Scene and its ok but I dont see any docs to tell me how to open or close the drawer!

This is my router :

```
<Scene
    key="TabbarWrapper"
    component={NavigationDrawer}
    initial={true} >
    <Scene key="Tabbar"
           tabs={true}
           initial={true}
           tabBarStyle={styles.tabBar}
           default="ProductExplorer">

        <Scene key="ProductExplorer"
               title="Lists"
               icon={TabIcon}
               iconName={"list"}
               initial={true}
               leftButtonIconStyle={{tintColor: "#FFF"}}
               renderBackButton={backButtonFunction}
               component={ProductExplorer}/>

        <Scene key="Profile"
               title="Profile"
               icon={TabIcon}
               iconName={"gear"}
               leftButtonIconStyle={{tintColor: "#FFF"}}
               renderBackButton={backButtonFunction}
               component={Profile}/>
    </Scene>

</Scene>
```

and this is my button renderer function :

```
let backButtonFunction = function () {
    var TouchableElement = TouchableHighlight;
    if (Platform.OS === 'android')TouchableElement = TouchableNativeFeedback;
    return (
        <TouchableElement onPress={()=>{ 
           **** my problem is here **** what do you think i should do?!what function must be call here to toggle open and close menu?
         }} style={{position : "absolute",left: 12,bottom:12}}>
            <Icon style={{color: "#FFF"}} name={"bars"} size={23}/>
        </TouchableElement>
    );
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answered in [this link](https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux/issues/1078)

in Drawer Component :

```
class NavigationDrawer extends React.Component {

    componentDidMount() {
        Actions.refresh({key: 'drawer', ref: this.refs.navigation});
    }

    render() {
        const state = this.props.navigationState;
        const children = state.children;

        return (
            <Drawer
                styles={drawerStyles}
                ref="navigation"
                type="displace"
                // onOpen={() => Actions.refresh({ key:  'drawer', open: true })}
                // onClose={() => Actions.refresh({ key: 'drawer', open: false })}
                content={<TabView />}
                tapToClose
                openDrawerOffset={0.2}
                panCloseMask={0.2}
                negotiatePan
                tweenHandler={(ratio) => ({
                main: { opacity: Math.max(0.54, 1 - ratio) }
        })}
            >
                <DefaultRenderer navigationState={children[0]} onNavigate={this.props.onNavigate}/>
            </Drawer>
        );
    }
}
```

custom button  :

```
renderMenuButton() {
    return (
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {Actions.get('drawer').ref.toggle()}}>
        <Icon name="ios-menu-outline" style={styles.navBarMenuIcon} />
      </TouchableOpacity>
    );
  }
```

and this is my Scenes :

```
 <Scene
                                key="drawer"
                                component={NavigationDrawer}
                                initial={true}
                            >
 /*another  Scene*/
</Scene>
```