# How to implement react-native-drawer in react-native-router-flux with redux?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-native, react-native-router-flux

I am trying to implement react-native-drawer in react-native-router-flux with redux. Tried following this example: https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux/blob/master/docs/OTHER_INFO.md but still getting an error: `Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) but got: object. Check the render method of 'DefaultRenderer'.`

What the correct way to implement the drawer in react-native-router-flux?

**EDIT - UPDATE: Yet still getting the error 'Element type is invalid...'**

**Quick Note: If I do Actions.drawer I get the error but if I do Actions.home nothing happens but the action REACT_NATIVE_ROUTER_FLUX_RESET is still being called**

```
const RouterWithRedux = connect()(Router)
const store = configureStore()

export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <RouterWithRedux>
          <Scene key='root'>
            <Scene component={Login} initial={true} key='login' title='Login'/>
            <Scene key="drawer" component={NavDrawer} initial={true}>
              <Scene component={Home} key='home' title='Home' type='reset'/>
            </Scene>
          </Scene>
        </RouterWithRedux>
      </Provider>
    )
  }
}
```

Then I press a button in Login and it triggers `Actions.` to navigate to. The NavDrawer is:

```
import React, { PropTypes } from 'react'
import Drawer from 'react-native-drawer'
import { Actions, DefaultRenderer } from 'react-native-router-flux'

import NavDrawerPanel from './NavDrawerPanel'

export default class NavDrawer extends Component {

  componentDidMount() {
      Actions.refresh({key: 'drawer', ref: this.refs.navigation});
  }

  render() {
    const state = this.props.navigationState;
    const children = state.children;

    return (
      <Drawer
        ref="navigation"
        type="displace"
        content={<NavDrawerPanel />}
        tapToClose
        openDrawerOffset={0.2}
        panCloseMask={0.2}
        negotiatePan
        tweenHandler={(ratio) => ({
          main: { opacity: Math.max(0.54, 1 - ratio) },
        })}
      >
        <DefaultRenderer
          navigationState={children[0]}
          onNavigate={this.props.onNavigate}
        />
      </Drawer>
    );
  }
}
```

And NavDrawerPanel is:

```
import React from 'react';
import {PropTypes} from "react";
import {
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
} from "react-native";
import { Actions } from 'react-native-router-flux';

const NavDrawerPanel = (props, context) => {
  const drawer = context.drawer;
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <TouchableHighlight>
        <Text>Home</Text>
      </TouchableHighlight>
      <TouchableHighlight>
        <Text>Profile</Text>
      </TouchableHighlight>
      <TouchableHighlight>
        <Text>Friends</Text>
      </TouchableHighlight>
    </View>
  )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    padding: 30,
    backgroundColor: 'black'
  },
})
```

Error:

[image]

Comment: You might have forgot to export your NavDrawPanel. Most probably it's just missing object exported from NavDrawPanel module.

Answer (score 0):

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39130083/how-to-open-drawer-when-use-a-custom-icon-in-scene) link...just copy and paste drawer component in first answer...
Try this code and replace with DefaultRenderer:

```
 <DefaultRenderer navigationState={children[0]} onNavigate={this.props.onNavigate}/>
```

Comment: Appreciate the suggestion and did as you advised but still getting the same error. Updated the original post, please take a look.

Comment: Quick Note: If I do Actions.drawer I get the error but if I do Actions.home nothing happens but the action REACT_NATIVE_ROUTER_FLUX_RESET is still being called

Comment: Checking to see if you've seen my last comment. Please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in your component.

Note that you are importing the drawer view like this:

```
import NavDrawerPanel from './NavDrawerPanel'
```

but if you take a closer look at the NavDrawerPanel file there isn't a default export. So instead of having

```
const NavDrawerPanel
```

you should have:

```
export const NavDrawerPanel
```

The error is a bit misleading but it's referring to the drawer's view not the drawer's component itself. Let me know if that does the trick :)